# Cant typecast variable to specific child class involving Generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics

> Note: Sorry could not come-up with better title than this, so please
>   suggest a better one if you come across one after reading the question

I have a `BasePresenter` class, That should take `BaseInteractor` and `BaseRouter` as its `init` arguments, and each child class of `BasePresenter` should be able to specify subclass of `BaseInteractor` and `BaseRouter` in their implementation

So I have declared my `BasePresenter` as

```
open class PRBasePresenter<T: PRBaseInteractor, R: PRBaseRouter> {
    var interactor: T!
    var router: R!
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    convenience init(with router : R, interactor : T) {
        self.init()
        self.router = router
        self.interactor = interactor
    }
}
```

So now `PRBaseCollectionsPresenter` which is a child of `PRBasePresenter` declares its interactor and router as

```
class PRBaseCollectionsPresenter: PRBasePresenter<PRBaseCollectionsInteractor, PRBaseCollectionRouter> {
   //other code here
}
```

Obviously `PRBaseCollectionsInteractor` is a subclass of `PRBaseInteractor` and `PRBaseCollectionRouter` is a subclass of `PRBaseRouter`

Everything works till here fine. Now comes the issue. Every `ViewController` should have `presenter` as a property. So I have a protocol which mandates that with

```
protocol PresenterInjectorProtocol {
    var presenter : PRBasePresenter<PRBaseInteractor, PRBaseRouter>! { get set }
}
```

And my `BaseViewController` confirms to `PresenterInjectorProtocol`

```
public class PRBaseViewController: UIViewController,PresenterInjectorProtocol {
    var presenter: PRBasePresenter<PRBaseInteractor, PRBaseRouter>!
    //other code...
}
```

Now lets say I have ChildViewController, it will obviously get `presenter` because of inheritance, but obviously child would want to have its specific `presenter` than having a generic one. And obviously **in Swift when you override a property you cant change the type of the variable**. So the only way is

```
class PRBaseTableViewController: PRBaseViewController {

    var tableSpecificPresenter: PRBaseCollectionsPresenter {
        get {
            return self.presenter as! PRBaseCollectionsPresenter
        }
    }
    //other code goes here
}
```

This gives me a warning

> Cast from 'PRBasePresenter!' to
>   unrelated type 'PRBaseCollectionsPresenter' always fails

And trying to ignore it and running will result in crash :(

How can I solve this problem? What am I doing wrong? Or is this approach completely wrong?

Comment: Not sure why is it occurred but just try to use it like `if let presenter = self.presenter as? PRBaseCollectionsPresenter` and then return value accordingly.

Comment: @kamaldeep-singh-bhatia : thanks for commenting buddy, but the issue is not presenter being nil, but the casting itself crashes saying trying to cast to wrong type :( If I put if let it might not crash but will never type cast it :( So I cant call child specific functions :(

Comment: oh, is it something related to this bug of Swift https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6140 ?

Comment: @kamaldeep-singh-bhatia : BINGO , as per the comment to bug "In general, G<A> cannot be downcast to G<B> even if A is a supertype of B. There are a few hard-coded exceptions in the type system, like for arrays and optionals."

Comment: now that I know two generics in swift cant be type casted, I wonder how can I even solve this now :(

Comment: @SandeepBhandari - To understand why you can't do this and in the process maybe discover how you might solve your problem another way research *covariance* and *contravariance*. Swift at this point in time doesn't support general variance, you can look at C# for a language which has more support.